# inappbrowser App rejected by Apple as does not currently contain iOS features or functionality

Tags: android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser, phonegap

I have developed an Android and Apple App using Adobe PhoneGap 6.5.0 with the Inappbrowser 1.6.1 (https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/5452). The website it points to is responsive (uses bootstrap) so displays very well on a phone or tablet and the published Android App works very well which has the same code base.

The problem I am having is Apple have rejected my app for the following reasons:

**From Apple:
Guideline 4.2.2 - Design**

*We noticed that your app only includes links, images, or content aggregated from the Internet with limited or no native iOS functionality. We understand that this content may be curated from the web specifically for your users, but since it does not sufficiently differ from a mobile web browsing experience, it is not appropriate for the App Store.*

**Next Steps**

*Please revise your app concept to provide a more robust user experience by including native iOS features and functionality.
We understand that there are no hard and fast rules to define useful or entertaining, but Apple and Apple customers expect apps to provide a really great user experience. Apps should provide valuable utility or entertainment, draw people in by offering compelling capabilities or content, or enable people to do something they couldn't do before or in a way they couldn't do it before.*

The following link has similar use of Inappbrowser and mentions success in submission to the Apple App store (" I have been successful in my attempts"):
https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/how-to-wrap-a-website-in-a-cordova-app

My Inappbrowser is setup in deviceReady as follows:

```
function onDeviceReady() 
{
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;

    if( isNetworkConnectionOk() )
    {           
        var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.yourwebsite.com', '_blank', 'location=no,hardwareback=yes');       
    }
    else
    {
        offlineCallBack();
    }   
}
```

There are also other event listeners to manage the network connection failing and GPS being turned off etc.

There are sites which offer a webview type solution and seem to guarantee Apple App submission (i.e. gonative.io) so it must be possible somehow.

I would just like to know if anyone knows how to resolve this problem to satisfy the Apple requirements? Are there native ios features or plugins etc. which you can add around the Inappbrowser for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Apple have some strict restrictions regarding some apps. I also faced a problem where Apple rejected my app because it was showing network connection alert due to low bandwidth. So, i have to contacted Apple and explain the situation and told them to try again at some specific bandwidth and after that within a day they have approved my app may be after testing.
So try to contact Apple and explain to them.

Comment: I did this myself and went through a few rounds of messages with them but they wouldn't budge. Very frustrating as my app does a couple things you can not get on the web. Now I have to add some silly other features to the app just to try and get it past Apple Review... lame.  

https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/6e2zgw/app_rejected_due_to_design_minimum_functionality/dk7l1nq/

Comment: A bit of a late update but ended up giving up with Apple and just had to go with Android. It was a long, painful and time consuming process that ended up being another issue to resolve when trying to get a business off the ground and unfortunately the product never made it live. Without having an app for Apple it basically killed the startup. Getting the Android app live was very straight forward.